# "Wait for Debugger" Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, decompiling, smali

I am using a guide to Decompile and Debug an APK but I can not pass the last step. Where when trying to Debug APK on my phone from Android Studio, an error appears: "Wait for Debugger". According to the guide I must execute the code:

```
adb forward tcp:5005 jdwp:$(timeout 0.5 adb jdwp | tail -n 1)
```

But since I do not have Linux (I have windows), I do not know what code I should execute. Thank you very much for your help!

Guide: https://malacupa.com/2018/11/11/debug-decompiled-smali-code-in-android-studio-3.2.html

Comment: You could try using Windows Subsystem for Linux, then you could follow your tutorial without having to try to translate the commands to work on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have adb in your path.
Then open a cmd.exe and run this command:

```
adb jdwp
```

and take note where application’s debug interface is listening. I'll call this value jdwp-port from now on.

Now execute the following command:

```
adb forward tcp:5005 jdwp:jdwp-port
```

and you should be fine. REMEMBER to change jdwp-port with the value you got from the first command.

Good luck.

> But since I do not have Linus (I have windows)

It is actually called Linux anyway.

As a side note, you should check the official AOSP documentation on how to use GDB here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb